# Electron / MacOS - Hide frameless window titlebar in fullscreen

Tags: macos, electron

I would like to have custom titlebar in fullscreen mode, but I can't get rid of the system one. I know I can set window to kiosk mode but I need to have access to menubar + have app on separate "desktop". Somehow Figma managed to do exactly what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC99D.png

Thanks :)